# Upgrade Entity Framework 4.0 to 6.0 not working

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

net MVC 2 to asp.net MVC 4 without any problem.

And then, I tried to upgrade entity framework 4.0 to entity framework 6.

The result is not good. I have about 15000 error.

I have this error appear several times

> The type or namespace name 'ComplexObject' could not be found

An other error

> Error 14331   The type or namespace name 'EdmComplexTypeAttribute' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

> Error 5460    The type or namespace name 'EdmEntityTypeAttribute' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I don't know where to begin.
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update templates too. In EF6 some types were moved to different namespaces and the code that is being generated is using namespaces from EF4/5. You can get [T4 templates for ObjectContext](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a) on VS Gallery. Also take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6) about moving your app to EF6 from an earlier EF version.

Comment: Additionally, from the article linked above: 
Note: If you are using Visual Studio 2012, you will need to install the EF 6 Tools to have this template. See Get Entity Framework for details. 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762